# Javascript with ASP classic loop not repeating

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asp-classic

I have a slight issue using the following javascript within an ASP loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder, location1, location2, gDir;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    gDir = new GDirections();
    GEvent.addListener(gDir, "load", function() {
        var drivingDistanceMiles = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1609.344;
        var drivingDistanceKilometers = gDir.getDistance().meters / 1000;
    var drivingTime = gDir.getDuration().html
        document.getElementById("<%=brokeridnum%>").innerHTML = '<strong>Address 1: </strong>' + location1.address + ' <br /><strong>Address 2: </strong>' + location2.address + '<br /><strong>Driving Distance: </strong>' + drivingDistanceMiles.toFixed(2) + ' miles taking ' + drivingTime;
    });
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">



    function showLocation(startpc, endpc) {
        geocoder.getLocations(startpc, function (response) {
            if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
            {
                alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the first address");
            }
            else
            {
                location1 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                geocoder.getLocations(endpc, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200)
                    {
                        alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the second address");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        location2 = {lat: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1], lon: response.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0], address: response.Placemark[0].address};
                        gDir.load('from: ' + location1.address + ' to: ' + location2.address);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    </script>
```

when the loop runs the javascript only displays inside the element once.

the <%=brokeridnum%> inserts a number into the JS and this is working correctly looking at the source from chrome.

the element with the id of brokeridnum is also working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   initialize();
   showLocation("postcode1","<%=destpc%>");
   </script>

<p id="<%=rsbkr("broker_id")%>"></p>
```

that is how the functions are called

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are using the [deprecated and turned off Google Maps Javasript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference).  You should port your code to [v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) ASAP (that isn't causing your problem though).

Comment: Do you mind posting complete code including ASP part? From your description it is all but impossible to figure out what is wrong. JavaScript part looks fine as well as Google API cal.

Comment: On top of my original comments, how many times are you expecting to see JavaScript function(same) to be defined and definition to appear on your page? That would 1. Create conflict and disable all JavaScript on your page; 2. Make no sense at all.

Comment: There is no loop in the code you posted. Without relevant code it's not possible to give any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Without seeing the entire script I can only guess...
Maybe instead of looping the entire script, try 
only looping the function call with a   parameter like this:

<% Do   . . . %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     initialize(<%= brokeridnum %>);
  </script>
<% LOOP . . . %>

The function now outside the loop waits for the brokerid parameter...

function initialize(brokerid){
.....
.....
document.getElementById(brokerid).innerHTML = '......
}

Sorry about abbreviating the code a bit, but I hope I helped.
```